# Can I use bash only instead of Drush to config revert and cache rebuild?

Tags: 8, deployment

Installing Drush on production servers can be difficult. I'm using rsync to move my file to the server. I only need to revert the config and rebuild the cache. Can I do that with pure bash and no extra dependency?

Comment: Is requiring Drush via Composer an option? You could then run your Drush commands via `vendor/bin/drush <your command>`.

Comment: You need drush to do the config import from command line. Otherwise I think you can use the UI, although I have never done that. To second, yes, you can try adding drush as a composer dependency.

Comment: @Gun5m0k3 I'm using Drupal without composer for the moment (not my choice and easier for frontend and junior). So I'm not super happy to add composer + drush on my production server...

Comment: Perhaps deploy a drush.phar along with your website? You can download a Drush phar from here: http://files.drush.org/drush.phar